# Parsing whitespace to resemble browser view

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm parsing through some data using javascript and getting results like that look like this:

```
" The big\n         brown     dog.     "
```

Of course, in a browser, this wouldn't look so funky:

> The big brown dog

But in a text editor, it would look like this:

```
  The big
        brown      dog
```

Any ideas on the cleanest way to parse this, so it looks like it is supposed to as plain text?:

> The big brown dog

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var string = " The big\n         brown     dog.     ";
string = string.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ");
```

This just matches all whitespace (when 2 or more whitespace characters are next to each other) and then replaces it with a single space.

Input (minus the quotes):

```
"The big\n         brown     dog.     "
```

Output (minus the quotes):

```
"The big brown dog. "
```